# Searching spotify user's music library for particular genre

Tags: iphone, ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

I am developing third party app on spotify platform. In that, user have to select spotify user's music library playlist (top 100 songs by Spotify user). So, I am trying to search spotify library for particular genre.
I am using `SPSearch` with Query `genre:pop`. But for some generics like "rock" it return nil.

I am using latest build of `cocoalibspotify`. Please can somebody tell how to get Spotify user track list or playlist for particular genre?

Comment: Hi @Rahul Mane, I am facing the same issue. Can you pls help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996772/get-the-list-of-genre-and-their-respected-songs-of-spotify-in-swift-ios

Comment: Hi @Rahul Mane, I have searched and then get to know that using https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations/available-genre-seeds API, we can get the list of Genres and to get the respective songs have to call https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=genre:%22rock%22&type=track&market=US&limit=20&offset=0 API. Is this the correct way?

Comment: Now you can see my question link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full advanced search documentation can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120704131650/http://www.spotify.com/us/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/).

Note that this will search the entire Spotify catalog, not just the user's own library. There's currently no built-in way to only search the user's library at this time.